# VBoxManage: error: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes

Tags: docker, docker-machine, bios

I have a fresh bare-metal installation of ubuntu 16.04 on a lenovo laptop.  I've downloaded virtualbox via apt-get, and am going through the docker tutorials.  I was going through the docker-machine docs and encountered the following error:

```
    21:11:57-~ $ docker-machine create --driver=virtualbox vbox-test
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(vbox-test) Copying /home/zach/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso to /home/zach/.docker/machine/machines/vbox-test/boot2docker.iso...
(vbox-test) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(vbox-test) Creating SSH key...
(vbox-test) Starting the VM...
(vbox-test) Check network to re-create if needed...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Unable to start the VM: /usr/bin/VBoxManage startvm vbox-test --type headless failed:
VBoxManage: error: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Details: 00:00:00.463735 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED, rc=NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005))
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.  Rebooting into the BIOS, I was finally able to enable something called "Intel TXT" which appeared to pertain to virtualization, but the large friendly menu is gone and the error persists.